# Is it possible to set archive.php instead of index.php to display blog?

Tags: loop, templates, archives, template-hierarchy, archive-template

I have index.php and archive.php in my theme, but I'd like to using archive.php to display blog and category posts.
Is it possible to override index.php by archive.php?

Comment: According to [WP hierarchy](https://wphierarchy.com/), _index.php_ is always the last template used. So _archive.php_ should already have priority over it.

Comment: So I don't know why it isn't.
My blog page is reading from index.php, but category post is reading from archive.

Comment: @kero You're misreading it. If you follow Blog Posts Index Page you'll see it goes home.php > index.php. It never uses archive.php.

Comment: @mm42 Are you using index.php for anything else? If you have an archive.php then the only thing it would be used for is the blog and search, so you could just rename archive.php to index.php. If you want the original index.php as a search template then rename index.php to search.php first.

Comment: I'm not using index.php at all. I'm using wp-bootstrap-starter and child theme, when I try to remove index.php, everything are broken. I'd like to create everything related with blog in archive.php

Comment: Don't remove index.php, just make archive.php into index.php.

Comment: @JacobPeattie how to do it?

Comment: Literally just rename the file...

Comment: Put content from archive to index?